# Remove eventhandler on .toggle in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove the eventhandler on .toggle()? Right now, it's set up so that it listens for a mouseclick, but I want .toggle() to execute on mouseover() instead.

I'm reading the method .toggle() method here, and it says the click can be removed using unbind():

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

But, I'm looking at the unbind method here:

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

And they only give examples of how to unbind html elements and css ids, not jquery functions themselves.

So my question is, is it possible to unbind the .click() from .toggle() and bind a .mouseover()?

If so, how would I do something like that?

Comment: (offtopic) just a demo to your newest deleted question: http://jsfiddle.net/H7Q3n/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `.hover()`.

Check the document ***[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)***.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#myObject").unbind("click")` should work